# Install default Mail App on my Nexus 5

Tags: email, apk

I do not see default mail App on my Nexus 5. I do have gmail though working fine. Probably I removed it earlier. How do I install it again ! I want to use that to configure Exchange Server on it to configure my official emails and calendars.

Currently when I try to do "Add Account" it does NOT show "Corporate" !

Comment: Have you by any chance updated the [Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.email) app from the Google Play Store?

Comment: After installing the Email app from Play Store; it does show corporate under "Add account" .. But still types shown are IMAP and POP only.. It does not show "Exchange" Account ! Please help.

Comment: Please see my answer below. You'll need to install Exchange2Google.apk as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the Email app directly from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.email).  If this app is shown as incompatible on your device, side-load it by downloading it from [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/06/18/googles-stock-email-app-finds-its-way-onto-the-play-store/), enabling the `Unknown sources` in Settings -> Security, and installing the apk (either by tapping the apk in the download manager, or via ADB from your PC: `adb install -r <path-to-apk>`).

Keep in mind though that this version sometimes breaks the Exchange functionality on some mostly non-Nexus devices. In order to resolve this, you need to also install a copy of latest Exchange2Google.apk app that is available for download from [here](https://app.box.com/s/ibr7ntxw3itvk8nt1nrn) or [here](http://d-h.st/nRM). You don't have to install it as a system app, just side-load it in the same manner as described above.